# Vampire power a.k.a Standby Power

Tags: current, electricity

What is the use of Vampire Power. Does it do any good?

Comment: Typically portions of the system are either kept on because waking them up would be annoyingly slow, or to do something like listen for a turn on command from an IR or radio remote.  This then often gets magnified by a power supply that can't efficiently supply only a tiny load, a design that doesn't do a good job of deactivating the unnecessary parts or the use of technologies or protocols that just don't power up quickly and so are kept hot.

Answer (score 1):

"Vampire power" is a term generally used to refer to those small loads that suck power all night (and generally through the day too) without much benefit to us.

There is an excellent example of tackling this in McKay's excellent, and freely available online, book Sustainable Energy Without the Hot Air. See Chapter 22 [Efficient Energy Use](https://www.withouthotair.com/c22/page_155.shtml).

[image]

*Figure 22.2. Efficiency in the offing. I measured the electricity savings from switching off vampires during a week when I was away at work most of each day, so both days and nights were almost devoid of useful activity, except for the fridge. The brief little blips of consumption are caused by the microwave, toaster, washing machine, or vacuum cleaner. On the Tuesday I switched off most of my vampires: two stereos, a DVD player, a cable modem, a wireless router, and an answering machine. The red line shows the trend of “nobody-at-home” consumption before, and the green line shows the “nobody-at-home” consumption after this change. Consumption fell by 45 W, or 1.1 kWh per day.*

> Does it do any good?

You can assume from the word 'vampire' that the term is derogatory. This is because the energy is (generally) wasted and little or no benefit is obtained.

Comment: So what is this so called "benefit"?

Comment: See the update.

Comment: Most of it is consumed to maintain "always on" functions (such as soft-on/off vs a Big Clunkin' Power Switch, clock displays or indicator lights on gizmos, that sort of thing).  Some of it is also burned in *no-load* consumption in wall-warts, battery-chargers, and such.

Comment: He turned off the answering machine while leavig!!??? Brilliant ideea! However, the cable modem and the wireless router are not in the vampire power category.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible reasons why something may never truly power off:

1. If you want to turn something on via a remote control, then some component must be powered on to detect the remote control signal.
2. Some things may take a long time to boot up from when power is first applied.  Putting the system into a low power "sleep" mode will allow it to start up quicker.
3. Some things, such as video recorders, use a built-in clock to wake them up at a pre-set time.  This can't work if the appliance is fully switched off.
4. More generally, anything with a clock display on the front will need power to show the clock.